# Image onload fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

I have a function being triggered when an image is loaded through the onload attribute in the image tag. This image is being appended to the DOM through some jQuery. The problem that I'm having is that when jQuery throws that image in, the function associated with onload fires 6 times. This isn't a compounding problem (eg. the first time, it fires once, the second time it fires twice), like some of the solutions I see. This fires 6 times consistently. Would anybody know why it is doing this?

Image triggering the function:

```
<img src='image_source.png' onload='myFunction();' />
```

Function:

```
function myFunction(){
  console.log('hello');
}
```

Hello shows up 6 times in the console log. Thank you for any insight you may be able to offer.

EDIT - here's the code that adds the image

```
$("[id=" + type + "]").html("<img src='" + image + "' class='loaded_image' onload='myFunction();' />");
```

Comment: is onload being handled anywhere else? Do you have anymore JavaScript you could show?

Comment: No. The only thing using onload is the image I'm inserting.

Comment: Do you perform any reload operations on the page? Is the image in an iframe? Does the image get added to the DOM more than once? You need to add that "some jQuery" code here to give us a complete picture.

Comment: Show the code where you add the images.

Comment: this is the jquery that loads the image
$("[id=" + type + "]").html("<img src='" + image + "' class='loaded_image' id='img_onload='myFunction();' />");

Comment: $("[id=" + type + "]").html("<img src='" + image + "' class='loaded_image' onload='onloady();' />");

Comment: @EricStrom Don't add code here, you're better off updating your answer. Is the code you mentioned in a loop? `id='img_onload='myFunction();' ` looks suspicious, the quotes aren't matching

Comment: It doesn't look like there's anything wrong, you should create a reduction at http://jsfiddle.net for us to look at. Many times, the process of creating a reduction will lead you to find the problem

Comment: Can you confirm how many objects this part of the code returns?  `$("[id=" + type + "]")`

Comment: `$("[id=" + type + "]")` is a div or span. Please explain It